# Error parsing parameter '--configurations': in AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell

I'm using Python's subprocess to call this command:

```
subprocess.call("aws emr create-cluster \
    --enable-debugging \
    --log-uri s3://e3-bucket/logs/ \
    --configurations https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/configurations/config.json \
    --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://bucket/file.jar,MainClass=spark_pkg.SparkMain \
    --release-label emr-5.3.1 \
    --ec2-attributes InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
    --service-role EMR_DefaultRole \
    --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=r4.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=4,InstanceType=r4.8xlarge \
    --auto-terminate", 
shell=True)
```

My config file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Classification":"spark",
    "Properties":{
      "maximizeResourceAllocation":"true"
    }
  }
]
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--configurations': Unable to retrieve https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/configurations/config.json: received non 200 status code of 301
```

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: Note: The subprocess call copy/paste makes the string look weird, but its showing up correctly in my script.

Comment: Does https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/configurations/config.json exist?

Comment: It doen't look like a Python error, since you got a 301 (Moved Permanently) error from your HTTP request. Maybe [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=725310) helps you

Comment: Why exec the awscli when you can use boto3 natively and have more control?